# Simple way to cluster histograms

Tags: clustering, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-sample

I'm trying to cluster set of histograms. The histograms represent the frequencies of the distribution for a numbers from 1 to 5. The following figure shows two samples of my data.

[image]

I have 10,000 histograms with fixed number of bins (5) and I'm looking for 
a simple clustering algorithm implemented in MATLAB, C# or C++, that can take the histograms and cluster them.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0509033.pdf) and [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-73560-1_12). I couldn't find an ungated copy of the second article.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second article is worth a mint. :) Thanks for this links!

Comment: I might try to use PCA to group them.  It is 5-dimensional continuous data, and you are trying to pack it into discrete bins.

Answer (score 5):

Use **hierarchical clustering** or **DBSCAN**.

They have one huge benefit over k-means: they work with arbitrary distance measures, and with histograms you might want to use like, for example, **Jensen-Shannon divergence**, etc. that are **designed to capture the similarity of distributions**.

Answer (score 1):

K-means could do this. K-means is an unsupervised clustering algorithm. Rewrite each histogram as a vector and use Euclidean distance.

This post goes into the assumptions of K-means: [How to understand the drawbacks of K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means) You might want to check these.

You have to determine the number of clusters yourself by estimating models with different k.