# clustering of numerical vector - distribution / pattern

Tags: r, clustering, python

I am interested to know which would be a best method to cluster the numerical vectors.

For example:

```
v1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1
v2 = 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,15,14,13,12,11
v3 = 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I am interested to cluster the vectors, based on the pattern or distribution of values. For example, vector 1 and 2 has higher values centered around the mid point, but vector 3 has higher values at the ends. How could I cluster them vectors i.e look the pattern or distribution of numbers , assuming that they are equally sized vectors.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to cluster variables/vectors by similarity of their frequency distributions, special distances for that exist. But just comparison of cumulative distributional shapes can be a good basis for clustering. See e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25764/3277. Search here also `clustering distributions`.

Answer (score 0):

Look for time series clustering, as your data has different length.

Don't forget preprocessing!

You will likely want to center and standardize the series.